# Uninstall app on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have installed a chrome app from chrome webstore. This app is a malware. Now I can't uninstall this app or any extension which is installed later from this web app from extension page of chrome. How can I uninstall this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App are not shown along with extensions `in chrome://extensions`
Try [Quick Uninstall](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plmejhjbbjhojedgpmfdnipgmkbkinpo?hl=en-US) to uninstall extensions or apps from chrome

Answer (score 3):

All extensions and plugins for Google Chrome can be accessed by typing `chrome://extensions` and about:plugins in the omnibar (address bar) of chrome. Try both these to see if any options exist to disable or remove the malware.

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the Chrome's Task Manager. See if the culprit process can be seen running here.

Be aware that the malware could have already gotten to your system; so changing settings in Google Chrome may not be very helpful. Try running your systems anti-virus to see if that picks anything up.

Comment: All the extensions do show up in chrome://extensions page. But still that culprit extension is not showing. I am also seeing a chrome icon in system tray bar. Which is obviously not created by chrome.

Comment: Edited the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's drag-and-drop to remove. Go to chrome://apps and click-and-drag to the "remove from chrome" text. The text does not appear until you have started to drag the application you wish to remove.